# Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured. When tried to use google cloud speech api

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-speech

I tried using Google cloud speech API after setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in system environment variable. Not able to figure out any issues or work around for more than 2 days.

Here is the error i am getting

```
24-May-2017 17:58:22.287 WARNING [grpc-default-executor-0] io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor.drain Runnable threw exception in ChannelExecutor
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:139)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:109)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiatorByType(NettyChannelBuilder.java:335)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:308)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DynamicNettyTransportParams.getProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:499)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:448)
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:61)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:209)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.obtainActiveTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:186)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$SubchannelImplImpl.obtainActiveTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:806)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getTransportFromPickResult(GrpcUtil.java:568)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:296)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$5.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:724)
    at io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor.drain(ChannelExecutor.java:87)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl.runSerialized(ManagedChannelImpl.java:715)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl.onUpdate(ManagedChannelImpl.java:752)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my POM File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.raghu</groupId>
    <artifactId>raghu</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>raghu</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.1-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Joda-Time -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- security-core for core authentication and access-control classes-->  
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency> <!-- security-web for web-security infrastructure code -->  
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency> <!-- security-config contains the security namespace parsing code -->  
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>raghu</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.1</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>raghu</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

JAVA implementation i tried

```
public String convertToText(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create();

        byte[] data = file.getBytes();

        ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
        System.out.println("1**********");
        // Builds the sync recognize request
        RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .build();
        RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
            .setContent(audioBytes)
            .build();

        // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
        RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
        List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

        String recText = "";


        for (SpeechRecognitionResult result: results) {
          List<SpeechRecognitionAlternative> alternatives = result.getAlternativesList();
          for (SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative: alternatives) {
            System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
            recText+= " "+alternative.getTranscript();
          }
        }
        speech.close();

        return recText;
    }
```

I am using to Tomcat (I don't want to use Jetty) to deploy my .war file.

There are lot of questions around the Internet none of them seems to be having the question answered! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Netty-tcnative 1.x is [incompatible with tcnative](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/151) as used by Tomcat. The incompatibility is resolved with netty-tcantive 2.x. Using the new netty-tcnative [required updates](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/151) to grpc-java, which will be included in the next release, 1.4.0, scheduled for June 6th.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you recommend me to wait till June 6th for the release ? or there are any workaround temporarily?

Comment: As a temporary workaround you could use [the Jetty ALPN agent](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.3.0/SECURITY.md#tls-with-jdk-jetty-alpnnpn) (it isn't Jetty itself; just a tool from the Jetty project) or use 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.